# Reformate data based on pattern in R

Tags: r, database, reformatting

I hope you can help me with this problem, I have the following data like this:

```
ID,colour
1,base_yellow
1,blue
1,base_red
1,blue
1,pink
1,blue
1,base_yellow
2,base_yellow
2,blue
2,base_red
2,blue
2,pink
2,blue
2,base_yellow
3,base_yellow
3,blue
3,pink
3,blue
3,base_yellow
4,base_yellow
4,blue
4,green
4,blue
4,green
4,blue
4,pink
4,blue
4,base_yellow
```

Every time meet with base (base_yellow, base_red), it creates new group, the output that is expected as shown below, which gives a new variable:

```
ID,colour
1,base_yellow; blue; base_red
1,base_red; blue; pink;blue;base_yellow
2,base_yellow; blue; base_red
2,base_red; blue; pink;blue; base_yellow
3,base_yellow;blue;pinkblue;base_yellow
4,base_yellow; blue;green;blue;green;blue;pink;blue;base_yellow
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following at all. Are these columns supposed to become a date, per the question title? Or is it the extra columns that are frustrating you? Some expected output would be very helpful.

Comment: I also can't understand what you're asking - I suspect you meant "reformat data" and not "date". Please clarify exactly what exactly are you trying to do. Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question will let you get help more easily.

Comment: Sorry @Dubukay for not clear question. I have changed the question to make it simpler. Hopefully, you understand the question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, @AndreaM for not a clear question. I have changed the question to make it simpler. Hopefully, you understand the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you might be able to adapt for your needs.

First, create a vector `vec` that includes row positions where `colour` starts with "base".

Then, you can use `map2_dfr` from `purrr` that will provide `colour` that ranges from start to end positions based on `vec`. This will help with situations where the same `colour` is used in more than one row in the end. A grouping variable `group` is also created in this step.

After grouping by `group`, you can keep only `colour` groups that have more than one `colour` and `str_c` to collapse them together for the same `group`.

```
library(tidyverse)

vec <- which(grepl("^base", df$colour))

map2_dfr(
  vec[-length(vec)],
  vec[-1],
  ~df[.x:.y, ],
  .id = "group"
) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(colour) > 1) %>%
  summarise(ID = first(ID), colour = str_c(colour, collapse = "; ")) %>%
  select(-group)
```

**Output**

```
     ID colour                                                              
  <int> <chr>                                                               
1     1 base_yellow; blue; base_red                                         
2     1 base_red; blue; pink; blue; base_yellow                             
3     2 base_yellow; blue; base_red                                         
4     2 base_red; blue; pink; blue; base_yellow                             
5     3 base_yellow; blue; pink; blue; base_yellow                          
6     4 base_yellow; blue; green; blue; green; blue; pink; blue; base_yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Read data
mydata <- tibble::tribble(~ID,~colour,
                          1,"base_yellow",
                          1,"blue",
                          1,"base_red",
                          1,"blue",
                          1,"pink",
                          1,"blue",
                          1,"base_yellow",
                          2,"base_yellow",
                          2,"blue",
                          2,"base_red",
                          2,"blue",
                          2,"pink",
                          2,"blue",
                          2,"base_yellow",
                          3,"base_yellow",
                          3,"blue",
                          3,"pink",
                          3,"blue",
                          3,"base_yellow",
                          4,"base_yellow",
                          4,"blue",
                          4,"green",
                          4,"blue",
                          4,"green",
                          4,"blue",
                          4,"pink",
                          4,"blue",
                          4,"base_yellow")

# Add column to group by words starting with "base_"
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(base = str_starts(colour, "base_")) %>% 
  mutate(base = ifelse(base, colour, NA)) %>% 
  fill(base, .direction = "down")

# Group by ID and words starting with "base_" and paste words
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(ID, base) %>% 
  summarise(colour = paste(colour, collapse = ";")) %>% 
  select(-base)
```

Results:

```
> mydata
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID colour                                                      
  <dbl> <chr>                                                       
1     1 base_red;blue;pink;blue                                     
2     1 base_yellow;blue;base_yellow                                
3     2 base_red;blue;pink;blue                                     
4     2 base_yellow;blue;base_yellow                                
5     3 base_yellow;blue;pink;blue;base_yellow                      
6     4 base_yellow;blue;green;blue;green;blue;pink;blue;base_yellow
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it did not work. Because, for it did not follow the expected output.